# Javascript iniciante - Passar argumento para javascript

Tags: php, javascript

```
<a onclick="onclick_edit(<?php echo 'aaa';?>);">

function onclick_edit(name){
    alert(name);
}
```

A função JavaScript nem sequer é chamada, só funciona se eu tentar passar número do PHP. Se eu tentar passar *string* do PHP não funciona. Funciona *string* só na mão, sem sair usar PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Quando você faz

```
onclick="onclick_edit(<?php echo 'aaa';?>);"
```

O resultado será o HTML

```
onclick="onclick_edit(aaa);"
```

Você pode confirmar isso visualizando o código fonte da sua página. Ao tentar executar, o JavaScript irá tentar passar a variável `aaa` para a função, dando erro de variável não definida (pode verificar no console isso).

Para que seja possível fazer o que deseja, você precisa exibir o valor com as aspas, para que o JavaScript entenda como *string*:

```
onclick="onclick_edit(<?php echo "'aaa'";?>);"
```

Assim o resultado será

```
onclick="onclick_edit('aaa');"
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou muito :)

Comment: @Visa [Como dizer obrigado em respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/605/5878)